# ASP.NET MVC HttpContext.Session object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpcontext

I have a question. I've built custom class in my project that contains public static property ctx and assingn HttpContext.Current object to it. In runtime that property seem to reference HttpContext object, but ctx.Session class is null. When i debug my app the left side of an expression (ctx) is not exactly the same as right side (HttpContext.Current). why this is happening?

Grettings

Answer (score 1):

HttpContext.Current is a singleton only for that request. By assigning the HttpContext.Current to a static variable you would be sharing this HttpContext.Current to an entire scope, which may not be right.

Session is a per user object while, static is an application wide object. Use static wisely.

Answer (score -1):

What I would do would be something like this.

1- a static class (ex: `ContextFactory`) which provides current httpcontext. If it has HttpContext.Current, then is provides that value, if not then it provides an assigned context. In your case, `new Mock<HttpContextBase>();`

```
public static class ContextFactory
{
    private static HttpContextBase current = null;

    public static HttpContextBase Current
    {
        get { return current ?? HttpContext.Current; }
        set { current = value; }
    }
}
```

2- Then I alter the code UserSess to

```
public static class UserSess 
{
    public static UserID
    {
        get { return ContextFactory.Current.Session["UserID"]; }
        set { ContextFactory.Current.Session["UserID"] = value; } 
    }
   //... 
}
```

sincerely

Comment: Do NOT store the session (=different per user) in a static variable (=the same for every user)!

Comment: as you can see, session is not stored in a static class unless user sets it (which must be done in a test). If not set, it will return the CURRENT http context, and CORRECT session.